# Rotate interface with UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, rotation

I've created a new "Tab Bar project" with the new Xcode 4.2.
The "new" way to work with UITabBar is different: Xcode doesn't create a xib file (with the UITabBarController), but it does everything via code.
Ok, let's do it.

So my code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is this:

```
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3;
UINavigationController *nav1, *nav2, *nav3;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    viewController1 = [[gemboy_iphone alloc] initWithNibName:@"vc1" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[concerti_iphone alloc] initWithNibName:@"vc2" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [[discografia_iphone alloc] initWithNibName:@"vc3" bundle:nil];

    nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

}
else {
  //same thing for the iPad version
}
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1, nav2, nav3, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window addSubview:self.splash.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

And it works.

My three .m files vc1.m, vc2.m and vc3.m (and also my iPad UIViewControllers) has this method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return YES;
}
```

The problem is that when I rotate the iPhone, it rotates only the status bar, and not the TabBarController!

Do you know why?
Thanks

Comment: It's kind of unusual that your three view controller classes are called gemboy_iphone, concerti_iphone, and discografia_iphone, but they reside in files vc1.m, vc2.m, and vc3.m you say. Are you sure that's right? XCode won't find those files just because their names are similar to the nib name. It will if they really contain those classes, and you have set the File's Owner type in the nibs to those classes.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely do not have to subclass UITabBarController, nor should you.

A tab bar controller will auto-rotate just fine IF all of its view controllers implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and return YES for the same orientations.

If you create a new project in Xcode 4.2 with the Tabbed Application template, you will see that it auto-rotates just fine.